# Prevent to create an account while credit card is declined in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

When the credit card is declined message is shown on the thank you page the account is created. Can anyone help me out how to prevent an account being created if credit card is declined. Using Stripe Payment plugin.

Comment: which payment gateway?

Comment: I have used stripe